# asp.net textbox.text and jquery.val()

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm reading the contents of a an asp.net TextBox on a button click event in the codebehind of a webpage.

This works fine if I type something into the box I can read whats in there via TextBox.Text.

However, if I copy into the input textbox using jquery, setting the contents using val(), I can see the text appear in the box but when the click event fires and I try to read the contents of the textbox it is always blank.  There's only every anything in there if I type it in myself.

The relevant bits of code are: -
The input box

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="deliveryAddress3" CssClass="required radius disabled sugestedAddressTargetCity bcity2" />
```

Javascript

```
var bfields = ['.baddress', '.bcity', '.bcountry', '.bpostcode'];
    var dfields = ['.baddress2', '.bcity2', '.bcountry2', '.bpostcode2'];
for (var i in dfields) {
                    $(dfields[i]).prev('label').hide();
                    $(dfields[i]).val($(bfields[i]).val());
                    $(dfields[i]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $(dfields[i]).addClass('disabled');
                    $(dfields[i]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Code in button click method of codebehind: -

```
customer.DelTown = deliveryAddress3.Text;
```

Whats going on here is that the customer can copy their address from one set of boxes to another.  If they do this (by clicking a button) the ext shows up in the boxes but in the code behind is blank.  However, if I type something in to those boxes it is available in the code behind.

Comment: It's going to be difficult for us to help without seeing any of your code.

Comment: dynamically added content from jQuery will not show in page source. I think this is what you are asking. Try to make your question more clear, and maybe add a jsFiddle, with example.

Comment: If you set the value attribute instead, does that work? Like this: `$("yourTextBox").attr("value", "newValue");`

Comment: using attr() worked once I'd removed the adding of the disabled property too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started a new ASP.net application and it works if you set the text box's `value` attribute using jQuery `attr()`.

The script updates the value inside the textbox and the code behind is able to read it too.

Designer HTML (added the below to the default.aspx):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="MytextBox"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="MyButton" Text="Click Me"/>
```

Rendered HTML output:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$MytextBox" type="text" value="NewValue" id="MainContent_MytextBox">
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$MyButton" value="Click Me" id="MainContent_MyButton">
```

Script:

```
$("#MainContent_MytextBox").attr("value", "NewValue");
```

Code Behind from default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Place Debugger here:
    if (MytextBox.Text == "NewValue")
    {
        // hurray
    }
}
```